# Cypress - How to Wait for an attribute value to be false in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a website which has everything in an iFrame. My scripts are failing because cypress is not able to wait for loading bar as cypress does not support iframes as of now. I want to write a custom command which wait until attributes 'ng-reflect-loading' value is changed to false.

I have tried with below code but its not working and halts cypress runner. Reference [Thread 136](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136#issuecomment-525994895)

```
cy.get('iframe').iframeLoaded().its('document').getInDocument('.main >ng-component > :nth-child(1)').then(function($loading) {
       while( $loading.attr('ng-reflect-loading')!='false')
       {
           cy.log('waiting')
       }
    })
```

Can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any insight of how iFrames work. But is 'ng-reflect-loading' eventually hidden? 
In that case this check should work:

```js
cy.get('.ng-reflect-loading')
  .should('not.exist')
```

If it remains existing but the value should change you could either check on the first value not existing:

```js
cy.get('.ng-reflect-loading')
  .should('not.contain.attr', 'attr_name', 'first value')
```

Or if the value changes, you could check for the second value to be available:

```js
cy.get('.ng-reflect-loading')
  .should('contain.attr', 'attr_name', 'second value')
```

Comment: Assertion fails with message - 'expected <ui-loading-indicator> to have attribute ng-reflect-loading with the value false, but the value was true'. 

I want to create custom command that should wait until the value is true. Something like this

 cy.get('iframe').iframeLoaded().its('document').getInDocument('.main > ng-component > :nth-child(1)').then(($loading) => { 
            while($loading.attr('ng-reflect-loading')!='false')
            {
                cy.log('waiting')
            }
        })